# Does Size Matter - 150 GB Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am being told that a new Site Collection I am requesting will allow for 150 GB in storage.  The unit I am providing some OOB help for is concerned that this 150 GB is not big enough as they want to store 30,000 documents per year with some small sized attachments.  These documents will all be Outlook emails along with the attachments.

I googled 150 GB, but I am still not clear on what represents 150 GB..however it seems like 150 GB is a Grand Canyon of space relative to what they want to store ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enquire as to how that 150GB number was reached (was that estimate from yourself?).  Microsoft provides some advice on estimating data capacity here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758645.aspx.

Are these emails always *guaranteed* to have an attachment (for example, PDF based invoices/sales receipts/etc)?  As suggested by others here, 150GB would give you only 5-6MB per email if there are indeed to be 30,000 emails per year.

Do you have any statistics on the size of emails previously received from this business unit?  If you could find this, you'd just then need to extrapolate that over the number of years that you expect to use the SharePoint site collection.

Also consider implementing some form of retention policy; you may wish to have data "expire" after a set amount of time (at which point it's archived somewhere else or simply deleted).  This could certainly minimize the amount of required space.

Answer (score 1):

It's tough to say. Is each attachment 6MB? That would exceed the 150GB space allocation for 30K items.

I would say gather their current set of files, find out what the file size is on disk, then add a few hundred more MB as it is not a 1:1 relation of file size to the data stored within the Content Database.